# How to make the radar plot align from the first spine angle and how to display the plot labels as tangent to the plot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, radar-chart

I was able to multi-scale data on a radar chart thanks to one user who developed a code, however, I'm stuck on the chart alignment and label alignment issues:

How can I align the radar plot with a spine (as in test1_sample) to be centered on the axis of the page?

How can I display the labels tangent to the plot so that they don't obstruct the chart and maintain clear display?

This is the code I tried:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def _scale_data(data, ranges):

    x1, x2 = ranges[0]
    d = data[0]

    sdata = [d]
    for d, (y1, y2) in zip(data[1:], ranges[1:]):
        sdata.append((d-y1) / (y2-y1)
                     * (x2 - x1) + x1)
    return sdata

class ComplexRadar():
    def __init__(self, fig, variables, ranges, n_ordinate_levels=5):
        angles = np.arange(0, 360, 360./len(variables))

        axes = [fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.9,0.9],polar=True,
                label = "axes{}".format(i))
                for i in range(len(variables))]
        l, text = axes[0].set_thetagrids(angles,labels=variables)
        [txt.set_rotation(angle-90) for txt, angle in zip(text, angles)]
        for ax in axes[1:]:
            ax.patch.set_visible(False)
            ax.grid("off")
            ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
        for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
            grid = np.linspace(*ranges[i],
                               num=n_ordinate_levels)
            gridlabel = ["{}".format(round(x,2)) for x in grid]

            gridlabel[0] = "" # clean up origin
            ax.set_rgrids(grid, labels=gridlabel, angle=angles[i])
            ax.spines["polar"].set_visible(False)
            ax.set_ylim(*ranges[i])
        # variables for plotting
        self.angle = np.deg2rad(np.r_[angles, angles[0]])
        self.ranges = ranges
        self.ax = axes[0]
    def plot(self, data, *args, **kw):
        sdata = _scale_data(data, self.ranges)
        self.ax.plot(self.angle, np.r_[sdata, sdata[0]], *args, **kw)
    def fill(self, data, *args, **kw):
        sdata = _scale_data(data, self.ranges)
        self.ax.fill(self.angle, np.r_[sdata, sdata[0]], *args, **kw)

variables = ("test1_sample", "test2_sample", "test3_sample","test4_sample", "test5_sample")

data = (80, 1000, 288,1, 10045)
ranges = [(1, 100), (100, 1000), (50, 400),(0.1, 1), (1000, 15000)]

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))
plt.style.use('classic')
radar = ComplexRadar(fig1, variables, ranges)
radar.plot(data)
radar.fill(data, alpha=0.2)
plt.show()
```

[Radar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Eg0A.png)

Answer (score -1):

Use this:
`ax.tick_params(pad=pad)`

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.